# Mount Error 13 - Permission denied 8 (zenworks)

Tags: linux, cifs

When i try to mount my share folder from windows 7 machine from network, this error occur me, any ideas how to solve them? My actual auto-running code below:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/zmg
mount -t cifs //10.20.30.1/zmg /mnt/zmg -o username=Provisorio/Administrator,password=zen,noserverino
```

Comment: I take it that Provisorio is the work group name and not an actual domain?

Comment: Did you try sudo?

Comment: provisorio is computer name, administrator is the user. I dont use a domain, instead of that i let workgroup name has a default (WORKGROUP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should probably specify the -o information prior to the address info i.e.
`mount -t cifs -o username=<USER>,password=<PASS> //<share-address>/<share-name> /mnt/mount-point`

As for why it is err-ing out, this could be due to your username, it seems like you are specifying the domain with the user, which is how you mount a share on Windows but not the same on unix, it should be just the username, if you want to specify the domain, add it to the end of the command like so `username=user,password=pass,domain=example.com

So in your case try using: 
`mount -t cifs -o username=Administrator,password=zen,domain=Provisorio,noserverino //10.20.30.1/zmg /mnt/zmg`

another reason the error 13 is appearing is due to folder permissions, so make sure you have the correct permissions on the wondows folder. for testing i'd say open the permissions up first to eliminate it as a possible cause!

To make this a permanent solution i.e. making it persistant after reboots add this line to the end of the `/etc/fstab` file ( you will need sudo permissions to edit this file! )
`//10.20.30.1/zmg /mnt/zmg cifs username=Administrator,password=zen,domain=Provisorio,noserverino 0 0`

Comment: Where can i get that fstab file? Im just take files from zenworks imaging cd and put on tftpd32 program on desktop which is a private network.
I dont have "etc" folder too, can i create it manually?

Comment: @firewallcj All UNIX based systems will have an `/etc` folder under the `/`(root) directory, this is the equivalent of window's C:\ folder, if you do not have access to this folder it may be because you are not an administrator? In this case it might just be best not to mess with the fstab file and you should just mount it and move your files. fstab would be useful if you need to access this mounted directory over an extended period of time, it seems like you just need to mount it once to take the image files you need no?

Comment: @firewallcj And no you should not create an /etc folder, for many reasons! and it would be pointless :) hope i helped, do let me know if you need more help and let me know if the mount worked

Comment: i follow your suggest and know i can mount successfuly, but give me (error 16, resource busy, and error 8), besides that i can access my network directory. how can i put printscreen here to show how my server is setup?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/zY4vMcJ.png

Comment: Aha! resource busy means you have it mounted successfully, it is trying to mount it again when it gives you this error, if you can access the network drive i would not worry about it!